# Canvas re-drawing gets stucked (performance-problem)

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, raspberry-pi, chromium

I'm about to create a GUI for my Raspi-Project. There is Nodejs running on the Raspi3 which runs a NodeJs-Server and a then it gets requested with Chromium in kiosk-mode.

One page of this GUI needs to visualize the states of 48x potentiometers, 12x buttons, 8x faders. The NodeJs-Server sends data (which was modified by user) via websocket to the client, which redraws the whole canvas. Works fine so far for a few elements:

[works fine but with a slight delay if you look closer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwsTO5nMzHM)

Now **the problem is, that whith the growing number of elements that need to be drawn, the performance drops down to unacceptable dalay-times.**

[works, but with a way too big dalay, as more elements are drawn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sw-A9xLWTbM)

and those are not even the half of stuff that needs to be drawn.

I am confused now, because I read about how fast canvas is, before I decided to go that way, and if I deactivate all canvas-drawings and simply `console.log()` the data that comes in via websocket, it is fast like in realtime.

so what am I doning wrong? maybe there it would be better not to draw the whole canvas on every value-change but animate the canvas? maybe someone has experience on this?

[Here is the code](https://github.com/AdmiralCrunch/raspiCanvasGUI/tree/master).. when you look into `assets/js/menu.class.js`, this is the file which generates the canvas. the function `createControllerGUI(options)` is called every via websocket, every time a value changes.

Comment: the question is incomplete without some code example of how a single element is drawn, is hard otherwise to understand where the slowness come from. chromium on raspberry could miss hardware acceleration for canvas too.

Comment: I pressed `save` too early, sorry. I updated the question with a github-link, as it is too much code to post here.

Comment: it looks like you redraw all the interface every change. you could consider trying an high level canvas library like fabricjs ( I m the author, so maybe bias ) that will give you object caching and redraw only what is actually changed. I m not writing this as an answer since i should provide at least an example on how to make a slider subclassing an object. seems a nice use case for a subclassing tutorial too.

Comment: Do you think you can reword the question to fit the stack overflow guidelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas is quick, but still cpu intensive. Also speed changes with the platform a bit.

Your function does all the drawing operation each change. Those operations have strokes, fills, center aligned text and something more ( i did not look all in details ).

There are some ways in which you can optimize the drawing operations.

### partial redrawing

maybe the most effective.
Keep track of where a widget is, keep track of what data changed from message to message and draw only the differences.
Use clearRect on the area occupied by the widget and redraw it. Do not touch the other pixels.
Unless an octopus is using the hardware, you will have 2 or 3 widget changing per frame at maximum.

### stroke all at once.

Instead of stroking on a per widget basis, you can trace all the paths you need at once, using a moveTo to the new position when changing widget, and using a single stroke operation at the end of the loop.

### caching

If you have some rotatory controls for example, you can draw them once on a small separate canvas, and use that canvas as a source image to be drawn at a different angle if you need to represent a rotated control.
DrawImage is often optimized with hardware operations while the single fill and stroke may not.

There are probably other ways, and you can look at high level libraries that can do this for you, exposing a widget logic instead of the low level drawing operations.

Comment: thanks bro! these are some very nice ideas! :) will try them immediately!

Comment: that really worked!! .. just by simply clear and redraw only the seperate parts that need to be updated, i have now a nearly realtime performance :) .. thank you bro! :)